# How to update existing record if the one being saved has the same key?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

MySQL has a very nice option for `INSERT` statement, which is particularly helpful for join tables without the `id` column.  It inserts a record, but, instead of throwing an error if its key clashed with the existing one, that record is updated.  Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO table (key1,key2,data) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=3;
```

How to achieve the same with Active Record?  The resultant code would then look like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :key1
  belongs_to :key2
end

record = Model.new
record.key1 = key1
record.key2 = key2
record.data = 'new data'
record.WHAT?    #Inserts or updates `data` for the existing record
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by j is the right idea, but you probably want to go with find_or_initialize_by to avoid multiple saves on the object. E.g.

```
record = Model.find_or_initialize_by_key1_and_key2 new
record.data = 'new data'
record.save
```

By the sounds of it, you also want a validation to check that the model doesn't allow duplicate joins too:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :key1
  belongs_to :key2
  validates_uniqueness_of :key1, :scope => :key2
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
record = Model.find_or_create_by_key1_and_key2(:key1 => key1, :key2 => key2)
record.update_attribute(:data, "new data")
```

**EDIT**

*zaius* idea looks better, you should use `find_or_initialize_by` to avoid multiple saves, as he said :]

Comment: Ooh, nice! I found documentation at [DynamicFinderMatch#new](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/DynamicFinderMatch.html#M001202), just click "Show Source".

Comment: Just a comment:  this advice appears to be more profound than it might seem due to the way it's presented...

Comment: -1 as it involves two writing SQL statements being emitted on creation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [composite primary keys](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/). It's a plugin for ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

First of that's a MySQL-specific solution, as far as I know that syntax doesn't work with any other SQL-servers. Usually called [Upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert) in discussions.

I'd go with making a new method called `save_or_update` and then if the save fails, with a duplicate key exception, load and `update_params`.

Comment: Your solution is not very performant.  When `save` fails, it also may roll back a transaction of notable size, and the data have to be loaded again.  As for MySQL, sorry, fixed the question.

Comment: `find` by itself will return `AR::RecordNotFound`, whereas `find_by_*` will return `nil`.